# Ember breaking after specifying route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following the ember tutorial at http://emberjs.com/guides/. My issue happens when they add the following to app.js.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return myPosts;
  }
});
```

Before I add this, the ember inspector does not have any problems. After I add this, the ember inspector tells me "Ember application not detected."

The code in my index looks like this. It is taken directly from the video.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <table class='table'>
            <thead>
              <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
            </thead>
            {{#each model}}
            <tr><td>
                {{#link-to 'posts' this}}{{title}} <small class='muted'>by {{author.name}}</small>{{/link-to}}
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you put your code into a jsBin?

Comment: Sure. [link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hemowowu/1/edit?html,js)

Comment: I cant work on your jsbin sample but for returning model you should use `return this.store.find('myPosts')` not `return myPosts`

Comment: Hm...didn't work. Still getting an error. It won't let me click on the 'posts' nav button. It does, however, recognize that there is a posts route in the #/ ember inspector tab...